# Check if data is added to array java

Tags: java, arraylist

I would like to check if the data is added to the array. when the data is inserted into the array i would like  to send a messagebox to the user.

what i have now is

```
public static ArrayList<ModuleData> modules;

public Module()
{
    modules = new ArrayList<ModuleData>();
}

public void addModule(String naamModule, int modulenr, int aantalUren, int weekBegin, int weekEind, String opleiding, int opleidingJaar)
{
    modules.add(new ModuleData(naamModule, modulenr, aantalUren, weekBegin, weekEind, opleiding, opleidingJaar));
}
```

I was thinking about return true or false if modules.add is succesfull

Comment: What is `modules`, a collection?

Comment: You could try saying `return modules.add(...)` since an ArrayList's `add()` method returns true if the collection was changed as a result of the call. So, if it was added the return would be true, and false otherwise.

Comment: If you found my answer satisfying, please set it as accepted (stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).

Answer (score 4):

`ArrayList` is a `Collection`, so `modules` will return `true` if it is changed upon insertion (as stated [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#add%28E%29)). If you receive `true`, something was added.

```
public void addModule(String naamModule, int modulenr, int aantalUren, int weekBegin, int weekEind, String opleiding, int opleidingJaar){
    boolean dataAdded = false;
    try {
        dataAdded = modules.add(new ModuleData(naamModule, modulenr, aantalUren, weekBegin, weekEind, opleiding, opleidingJaar));
    } catch (Exception e) {
       // handle exception
    }

    if( dataAdded ){
       // notify user about success 
    }
}
```

Or you can rewrite the `addModule()` method to return `dataAdded` and handle the response outside.

Answer (score 1):

```
public boolean addModule(String naamModule, int modulenr, int aantalUren, int weekBegin, int weekEind, String opleiding, int opleidingJaar)
{
    boolean added = true;
    try {
        modules.add(new ModuleData(naamModule, modulenr, aantalUren, weekBegin, weekEind, opleiding, opleidingJaar));
    } catch (Exception e) {
       added = false;
    }
    return added;
}
```

Adding logs and handling method inputs will be good too.